# Random Crashes on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, desktop-computer

My computer is crashing randomly, sometimes it gives Error Code and sometimes it just restarts. The Error Code I have received are `Kmode Exception Not Handled`, `Page Fault in Non-Pages Area`, `IRQL Not Less or Equal` *etc...*
I have played some games with High Graphic, and these are working fine.

Recently I have upgraded my PC with **Radeon RX 470 Nitro**, **128GB SSD** & **500W PSU**.

***What I tried***

- I removed the latest of AMD for my Graphic and let Windows 10 to get the drivers of Graphics Card of himself.
- I updated Windows 10

> ***My PC Information***
>
> - CPU: AMD FX-6120 (Six-Core Processor)
> - Motherbaord: AsusTeK CM1855
> - 8 GB Ram (3.92 GB Usable)
> - Radeon RX 470 Graphics (4GB)
> - Windows 10 (10.0.18363 Build 18363)

***Update 1***

I'm running both CPU and GPU benchmark. CPU benchmark successfully completes but computer restarts while running GPU benchmarking. If it is GPU related issue then why it sometimes gives Windows Error Code?

***Update 2***

I'm running Heaven Benchmark 4.0, and at first, my PC hanged and on the second attempt, some frames were glitched.

Comment: WDDM is heavily used by the Windows kernel.  If there is something wrong with your GPU, then the kernel would be encountering problems, if caused by hardware problems it wasn't able to recover from.  You should use windbg to properly diagnose your problem.

Comment: @Ramhound how can I use **WinDbg** to check the problem...